# How to implement scrollable FutureBuilder Flutter

Tags: flutter

How do i implement a scrollable futurebuilder?

I have this snippet. but rather than make it scroll up, it just does not scroll at all.

The snippet looks like this :

```
    Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<TransactionDetails>>(
            future: fetchAlbum(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        leading: CircleAvatar(
                          child: Image.network(
                              snapshot.data![index].avatar.toString()),
                        ),
                        title:
                            Text(snapshot.data![index].name.toString()),
                        trailing: Text(
                            snapshot.data![index].amount.toString()),
                        subtitle: Text(
                          snapshot.data![index].date.toString(),
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 9),
                        ),
                      );
                    });
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('${snapshot.error}');
              }
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            }))
```

How do I get it to do something like that scroll? Please I need some help here.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have enough data to scroll the view. in case you don't have enough data to scroll and want the scroll UX.  i'll suggest you add the scroll physics to list view.

```
ListView.builder(
        physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        shrinkWrap: true,
)
```

Comment: Have updated to your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping the `FutureBuilder()` with a `Column()` because of your `ListView.builder` and then wrap the Column with a `SingleChildScrollView()`. The Column widget always tries to expand as big as it can, so you wrap it with a SingleChildScrollView to make it scrollable. The ListView.builder is already a scrollable by it self, but since you need to scroll the whole FutureBuilder you can do it this way. If you want to disable the list view inside the ListView.builder, you can use `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()`.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
child: Column(children:[
 Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<TransactionDetails>>(
            future: fetchAlbum(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        leading: CircleAvatar(
                          child: Image.network(
                              snapshot.data![index].avatar.toString()),
                        ),
                        title:
                            Text(snapshot.data![index].name.toString()),
                        trailing: Text(
                            snapshot.data![index].amount.toString()),
                        subtitle: Text(
                          snapshot.data![index].date.toString(),
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 9),
                        ),
                      );
                    });
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('${snapshot.error}');
              }
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            }))

]),
),
```

Comment: Sorry, it did not work as expected.